# Assetic: excessive 0x00 characters at the end of asset files

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, vagrant, assetic

I using Symfony 3 with Assetic under Vagrant box with Debian as guest and Windows as host. I set assetic.use_controller to false to speed up loading web pages in dev environment. When I run assetic:dump, it refreshes the assets properly, but adds random amount of 0x00 characters to the end of some asset files. So when I refreshing the page in browser, I get javascript error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". Here is the screenshot from chrome's console:

[image: Here is the screenshot from chrome's console]

Those red dots are characters with 0 code. It appears with random length in some js files.

**If I manually remove assets directory and run assetic:dump again, then the problem disappears.**

I think I can write custom symfony command to remove assets directory and then run assetic:dump from inside of it, but it does not help if I will use great command assetic:watch.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** I found that it's not an Assetic bug. Actually, problem was found in Nginx. I solved it by changing it's config like described at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/645425).